# 2007 Maxima transmission lines hose clamp size

Tags: nissan, maxima, hose, hose-clamp

I just replaced the radiator on my 2007 Nissan Maxima and the 2 transmission hose clamps were rusted and cracked.

I would like to replace them, but I don't know what size they are. Anyone have this info? Thanks!

Comment: What's the outer diameter of the hose? It's probably around a #4.

Comment: Please put it down as an answer so the question gets marked as "answered"

Comment: @Zaid not sure this question adds a lot to the quality of the knowledge on here...

Comment: The quality and usefulness of any Q&A is something decided by the community, that's what voting is for

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting a 3/8" hose clamp from Home Depot and it worked!